# $T^m(v)=v$ implies $T$ diagonalizable

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

> Suppose $V$ is a vector space over $\Bbb C$, and let $T:V\to V$ be a linear transformation. such that there exists $m\in \Bbb N$ such that $T^m(v)=(v)$. Prove that $T$ is diagonalizable.
>
> **Proof:** Fix a basis $v_1,\dots,v_n$ of $V$. Let $m_1,\dots,m_n$ be such that $T^{m_i}v_i=v_i$. Let $n=\text{lcm} \{n_i:1\le i \le d\}$. Then $T^n(v)=v$ for every $v\in V$, so over $\Bbb C$, the characteristic polynomial has distinct roots.

I can't understand why it has *distinct* roots.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The book is using sloppy language.  Of course, the characteristic polynomial need not have distinct roots.  The author meant to say that the *minimal* polynomial has distinct roots, which you can see because $x^n-1$ has no repeated roots, the roots being the $n$ $n^{th}$ roots of unity.  (And since T satisfies $x^n-1=0$ its minimal polynomial must divide $x^n-1$.)

Note that the book is also sloppy in not quantifying $v$ and $m$ in the statement of the problem.  The author really should have said either "for every $v$ there is some $m$..." or "there is some $m$ such that for every $v$...".  Even though the problem works in either of those formulations, it prevents the misreading "For some $v\ne 0$ and some $m\ge 1$..." which would of course not work.

Comment: Why is it so that the characteristic polynomial need not have distinct roots? I read on [Wikipedea](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimal_polynomial_(linear_algebra)) that $\lambda$ is root of minimal polynomial if and only if it is root of characteristic polynomial.

Comment: "Distinct roots" means that when you factor the polynomial into linear factors of the form $(x-a)$ no such factor appears more than once...i.e, no repeated roots.  The characteristic and minimal polynomials will have the same roots, but it will often be the case that a root is a repeated root in the characteristic polynomial but not in the minimal polynomial.

Comment: Thank you very much. Just one more thing: how did you get minimal polynomial $x^n-1$?

Comment: Since $T^n-1=0$ the minimal polynomial is a *divisor* of $x^n-1$.  Since $x^n-1$ has distinct roots so must any divisor of $x^n-1$.

Comment: @CMonsour Perhaps it's worth mentioning that $x^n-1$ has no repeated roots because it shares no roots with its derivative $nx^{n-1}$.

Comment: @CMonsour But, since characteristic polynomial of $n\times n$ matrix has at most $n$ roots, in this case characteristic polynomial will not have repeated solutions, right?

Comment: @ Silent, you are confusing yourself because you have used the same variable $n$ for two different quantities.  There's no reason the lcm of the m's should be the same as the dimension of the matrix.

Comment: @CMonsour, I am so thankful for clarifying that. This is last question: so, $\text{lcm} (m_1, \dots, m_n)\ge \dim V=n$?

Comment: No, it could be larger or smaller.  For example, it T is the identity matrix then the lcm can be 1 and dim V can be 124 or whatever.  On the other hand, if dim V=1 the lcm can be as big as you like--for T=-1 it's 2, for T=i it's 4, etc.  Of course, in these latter cases the minimal polynomial is a proper divisor of $x^2-1$ or of $X^4-1$.